# android service, context, builder

Tags: java, android, android-service, builder, android-context

I read around in Android Developer, but I didn't understand completely those 3 "ideas":

1) context

2) builder

3) service

and how do they relate to each other?

I saw for example:
`GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)`

and I didn't get exactly what the general purpose of each "idea".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GoogleApiClient.Builder` is a class that configures and returns an instance of `GoogleApiClient`. The term *Builder* refers to the **Builder pattern**.

`Context` is what its name suggests: the *who* or *what* that wants to use a particular feature of the framework.

`Service` is a component that performs an operation without requiring a front-facing UI. A `Service` or an `Activity` can provide an instance of `Context` as `MyService.this` or `MyActivity.this`.

> how do they relate to each other?

Here it seems that you are trying to perform an action related to Google Play Services through an Android `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

Context is a thing that you can get everything from it, like the resource(pic, string,color...), etc.

Builder is a thing that builds something. There can be StringBuilder for building string, etc.

Service is a class that runs in the background, I mean, no GUI and you can't see it but it is working. It is like the service in our lives.

Answer (score 0):

`Context` : As the name suggests, its the context of current state of the application/object. It lets newly created objects understand what has been going on. Typically you call it to get information regarding another part of your program (activity, package/application)

You can get the context by invoking `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()` or this (when in the activity class).

`GoogleApiClient.Builder` is a class that returns a single instance of `GoogleApiClient`.

`Service` is to  perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user.

Answer (score 0):

The context shows the state of the application and provides access to resources and allows the creation of new objects (for example views).

Builder is an implementation of [the Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), that allows the creation of new objects avoiding the telescoping constructor anti-pattern (increasing the number of constructor parameters and/or the number of constructors).

A [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is a component that does not provide UI and performs long-running operations. It will run in background even if the user switches to another application.